# pycharm highlighting issue - last line highlighted different color

Tags: pycharm

I do not know how to describe the attached highlighting issue. When I choose the bright color scheme, the default background is black, and when I chose a dark color scheme, it is this white color. I have no idea how I did it, nor how to fix it. It is driving me nuts. Any help is sincerely appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly was changed, but you can restore the defaults with **Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Gear button | Restore Defaults...**:

[image]